# Batch insert values to a specific column in sqlite3 on iOS

Tags: ios, sqlite

I have a table in my database. I want to add values to a specific column in the table. Since there are like thousands plus rows in my table i figured i have to use batch update. The code is this but i get syntax error and a message saying there is no such row:

```
NSString *addProductColQuery = @"ALTER TABLE Sale ADD COLUMN Product text";
[self.dbManager loadDataFromDB:addProductColQuery];

NSString *batchstart = @"BEGIN IMMEDIATE TRANSACTION";
[self.dbManager loadDataFromDB:batchstart];
for (int i = 0; i<self.productInfo.count; i++)
{
    NSString *addValue = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"INSERT INTO Sale (Product) VALUES (%@)",[tempProductArray objectAtIndex:i]];
     [self.dbManager loadDataFromDB:addValue];
}
NSString *batchComit = @"COMMIT TRANSACTION";
[self.dbManager loadDataFromDB:batchComit];
```

**Update:**
I have managed to get the above code to work but now i am getting 90% CPU Usage on iphone6! I actually saw this coming since im using a for loop which is dead wrong to loop a query. Is there a way to batch insert the values to the rows in a specific column?

Comment: If you're still having problems, share the exact error message that you got from `sqlite3_errmsg` (or if using `sqlite3_exec`, what you're getting from the fifth parameter to that call).

Answer (score 1):

Are the values in `tempProductArray` text values? If so, you have to quote them in your SQL:

```
NSString *addValue = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"INSERT INTO Sale (Product) VALUES ('%@')", tempProductArray[i]];
```

Having shown you a quick solution, that's actually the wrong way to do it. It is inadvisable to use `stringWithFormat` to build SQL with text values. If any of those strings themselves have apostrophe characters in them, the SQL will fail. Also, if any of this data was provided by the end-user or from the network, you're exposed to SQL injection attacks.

The correct solution is to use `sqlite3_prepare_v2` of the SQL without quotes, but with `?` placeholder:

```
NSString *addValue = @"INSERT INTO Sale (Product) VALUES (?)";
```

And then, before calling `sqlite3_step`, you would call `sqlite3_bind_text` to bind a text value to the `?` placeholder.

If your `dbManager` doesn't offer that capability, you'll have to add it. Or use a library, like [FMDB](https://github.com/ccgus/fmdb), that offers this capability out of the box.